# SSL Certificate validation always pass

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm trying to setup a self hosted WCF service, exposed in endpoint with https address, and I want just certain clients can call the service.
Client authentication should be done by certificate provided by client.
I'm in a corporate network, all certificates are issued by same authority, so i'm using certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" in server side to identify authorized clients.

The server certificate binding to port is done.
Service binding configured as:

```
  <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
  </security>
```

Service behaviour configured as:

```
  <serviceCredentials>
    <clientCertificate>
      <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"></authentication>
    </clientCertificate>
  </serviceCredentials>
```

The client certificate is in windows trust (trusted people) in server side.

The server certificate is in windows store (trusted people) in client side.

Communication between client and servers works OK so far...SSL handshake OK...

but, when I remove the client's certificate from Trusted People on server side, the client still can call the service, and I'm expecting just the opposite: 
"If client's certificate not in server trusted people store, then dont accept call."

all cache already removed, server restarted... client app still can call the service from same previously authorized client workstation.

any suggestions ??

Comment: Maybe you have that cert in another place too, like Personal, etc?